# Hide header bar on single Tab Screen

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

[image: HEader on the pages that i want to keep] [image: On Sleep component i want to remove green header]I ve got nested navigation, and I would like to hide a header bar from a single page from my bottom tab navigation(I am doing this because I want to have a different color ). So I managed to do that by creating the SleepStackScreen component and give the header the color that I want, but now I am having two headers, one from the TabScreen component and one from the SleppStackScreen.

Any hint of how could I hide the TabScreen header only on SleepStackScreen.

I already tried with `options={{ headerShown: false}}` but no luck.

The green header on the first picture i want to keep it on existing pages, whereas on the second picture I want to remove it and to keep the blue one

```
const SleepStackScreen = ({navigation}) => (
  <SleepStack.Navigator
    screenOptions={{
      headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: '#1f65ff',
      },
      headerTintColor: '#fff',
      headerTitleStyle: {
        fontWeight: 'bold',
      },
    }}>
    <SleepStack.Screen
      name="Sleep"
      component={Sleep}
      options={({navigation, route}) => ({
        headerTitle: (props) => <Header {...props} />,
      })}
    />
  </SleepStack.Navigator>
);

const TabsScreen = () => (
  <Tabs.Navigator shifting={true} initialRouteName="Home" activeColor="#fff">
    <Tabs.Screen
      name="Home"
      component={Browser}
      options={{
        name: 'sal',
        tabBarLabel: 'Home',
        tabBarColor: '#009387',
        tabBarIcon: ({color}) => (
          <MaterialCommunityIcons name="home" color={color} size={26} />
        ),
      }}
    />
    <Tabs.Screen
      name="Sleep"
      component={SleepStackScreen}
      options={{
        tabBarLabel: 'Sleep',
        title: 'sal',
        tabBarColor: '#694fad',
        tabBarIcon: ({color}) => (
          <MaterialCommunityIcons name="sleep" color={color} size={26} />
        ),
      }}
    />
    <Tabs.Screen
      name="Settings"
      component={SettingWithContext}
      options={{
        tabBarLabel: 'Settings',
        tabBarColor: '#009387',
        tabBarIcon: ({color}) => (
          <MaterialCommunityIcons name="settings" color={color} size={26} />
        ),
      }}
    />
  </Tabs.Navigator>
);

export default CreateStack = () => {
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = React.useState(true);
  const [userToken, setUserToken] = React.useState(null);

  const authContext = React.useMemo(() => {
    return {
      signIn: () => {
        setIsLoading(false);
        setUserToken('asdf');
      },
      signUp: () => {
        setIsLoading(false);
        setUserToken('asdf');
      },
      signOut: () => {
        setIsLoading(false);
        setUserToken(null);
      },
    };
  }, []);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setIsLoading(false);
    }, 1000);
  }, []);

  if (isLoading) {
    return <LoadingScreen />;
  }
  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={authContext}>
      <NavigationContainer>
        {userToken ? (
          <Stack.Navigator
            initialRouteName={Browser}
            screenOptions={{
              //headerShown: false,
              headerStyle: {
                backgroundColor: '#009387',
              },
              headerTintColor: '#fff',
            }}>
            <Stack.Screen
              name="Browser"
              component={TabsScreen}
              options={({route}) => ({
                headerTitle: getHeaderTitle(route),
              })}
              options={({navigation, route}) => ({
                headerTitle: (props) => <Header {...props} />,
              })}
            />
            <Stack.Screen
              name="PreScreen"
              component={PreScreen}
              options={({navigation, route}) => ({
                headerTitle: (props) => <Header {...props} />,
              })}
            />
            <Stack.Screen
              name="PreScreenSleep"
              component={PreScreenSleep}
              options={({navigation, route}) => ({
                headerTitle: (props) => <Header {...props} />,
                headerStyle: {
                  backgroundColor: '#694fad',
                },
              })}
            />
            <Stack.Screen
              name="Player"
              component={Player}
              options={({navigation, route}) => ({
                headerTitle: (props) => <Header {...props} />,
              })}
            />
          </Stack.Navigator>
        ) : (
          <AuthStack.Navigator initialRouteName={RegisterLogin}>
            <AuthStack.Screen
              name="RegisterLogin"
              component={RegisterLogin}
              options={({navigation, route}) => ({
                headerTitle: (props) => <Header {...props} />,
                headerStyle: {
                  backgroundColor: '#f4511e',
                },
              })}
            />
            <AuthStack.Screen
              name="Login"
              component={LoginWithContext}
              options={({navigation, route}) => ({
                headerTitle: (props) => <Header {...props} />,
              })}
            />
            <AuthStack.Screen
              name="Register"
              component={RegisterWithContext}
              options={({navigation, route}) => ({
                headerTitle: (props) => <Header {...props} />,
              })}
            />
          </AuthStack.Navigator>
        )}
      </NavigationContainer>
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE as of version 5**

As of version 5 it is the option headerShown in screenOptions

Example of usage:

```
<SleepStack.Navigator
  screenOptions={{
    headerShown: false
  }}
>
  <SleepStack.Screen
  name="Sleep"
  component={Sleep}
  options={({navigation, route}) => ({
    headerTitle: (props) => <Header {...props} />,
  })}
/>
</SleepStack.Navigator>
```

ok try this

```
<SleepStack.Navigator
  screenOptions={({ route }) => { 
    let shown = true;
    if (route.state.routeNames[route.state.index] === "Sleep") {
      shown = false;
    }
    return {
      headerShown: shown
    };
  }}>
  <SleepStack.Screen
    name="Sleep"
    component={Sleep}
    options={({navigation, route}) => ({
      headerTitle: (props) => <Header {...props} />,
    })}
  />
</SleepStack.Navigator>;
```

Comment: Indeed in this way I am removing the header from SleepStackNavigator, but what i want to do is to keep the header from Sleep Stack Navigator and to remove the Stack Navigator header only on Sleep Stack Navigator, and to keep Stack Navigator header on the other screens. I uploaded some pictures for clarification

Comment: I think the header should be hidden in <Stack.Navigator> tho